# How to quickly peel a bag of potatoes

Tags: food, efficiency, time

There have been several times that I have had to make a huge potato salad or a lot of mashed potatoes in a short amount of time. I usually have to use an entire bag of potatoes (I have a big family). I am pretty good at doing everything except peeling the potatoes. **Is there any way to quickly peel an entire bag of potatoes?**

Comment: I'm pretty sure you already tried the Willy Waller 2006 ? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NSfBpXOzmd0

Comment: I used to work in a UK Fish and Chip shop in the 80s, and we had an enormous spinning barrel that was rough inside, and sprayed water into the barrel. It would remove the skins of pounds of potatoes in seconds.

Comment: I invented that machine when I read the question, @MatthewLock. They use [similar ones to defeather chickens in plants](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=plucking%20machine&ia=products), as I mention in [one question of mine](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/417/plucking-a-chicken-without-a-machine). I was wondering of the same could be done for potatoes....interesting. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### The Super Peeler

<sup>**Warning:** only do this outside</sup>

This method takes some time to prepare, but you only have to prepare it once and every other time you do it, it will be ready.

You need a bucket, a hose, a drill, and a **new** toilet bowl brush. Drill a hole in the bottom of the brush's handle and keep the drill there. Spin the brush a few times to make sure it sticks. Fill the bucket with the potatoes. Now put the brush attached to the drill in the bucket, between the potatoes. Start filling the bucket with water, while you spin the brush using the drill. In about 60 seconds, all of the potatoes will be peeled.

[image: Toilet bowl brush attached to a drill]

<sup>Image from [ThriftyFun](http://www.thriftyfun.com/Making-a-Powered-Scrub-Brush.html)</sup>

Comment: Should be able to able to sell this to the US Army and make lots of money!

Comment: While this setup is fine with a wireless drill, for a wired one I'd recommend using a much longer portion of the brush handle and being careful when pouring in the water. Electric shocks from drilling water probably aren't fun.

Comment: There's a special bowl for Kenwood stand mixer whose walls are like sandpaper. It can be used to peel vegs or clean mussels. A bit like your idea, but the scrubbing is done by the bucket.

Comment: I like the emphasis on the **new** toilet brush.

Comment: A brush that you can use in new toilet bowl? :D

Answer (score 13):

Leave the skins on, thats where the vitamins and fiber are. People pay stupid amounts of money for potatoes with skins on from processed food manufacturers and we get potatoes from the store and peel the best bit off..!

Answer (score 8):

If you boil the potatoes first, you can peel them by simply rubbing the skin off of them. (And you are not likely to require medical attention with this technique!)

It's explained nicely [at this link](http://creeklinehouse.com/2013/11/super-terrific-tip-for-speed-peeling.html) from Creek Line House. They say it takes about two seconds per potato. I've used this method myself. It works. If you can handle the hot potatoes (use a rag or some glove to handle them), you can skip the ice step.

[image]

Comment: Put the hot (boiled) potatoes in chilled water for ~10s for even easier peeling

Answer (score 1):

I you are making mashed potato using a ricer, don't peel your potatoes, instead cut them in two, boil them and then when you put them in the ricer put the exposed potato facing downward so that it is squeezed through the holes leaving the skin behind.